# How to convert GroovySOAP client code into groovy-wslite?

Tags: grails, soap, groovy

Hi I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how I can access this web service: http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

Using the groovy Wslite library, seems to work fine with the depreciated Groovy Soap library but I am not allowed to use that.

The libraries are described here:
[Groovy Soap Use](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+SOAP)

[Groovy-Wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite)

I am totally new to groovy and these technologies in general so forgive my ignorance.

Basically I want this code:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.net.soap.SoapClient

proxy = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL")

def currency = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CAD', 'GBP', 'AUD']
def rate = 0.0

swing = new SwingBuilder()

refresh = swing.action(
  name:'Refresh',
  closure:this.&refreshText,
  mnemonic:'R'
)

frame = swing.frame(title:'Currency Demo') {
 panel {
         label 'Currency rate from '
         comboBox(id:'from', items:currency)
         label ' to '
         comboBox(id:'to', items:currency)
         label ' is '
         textField(id:'currency', columns:10, rate.toString())
         button(text:'Go !', action:refresh)
       }
 }
 frame.pack()
 frame.show()

 def refreshText(event) {
   rate = proxy.ConversionRate(swing.from.getSelectedItem(), swing.to.getSelectedItem())
   swing.currency.text = rate
}
```

Converted to work with the groovy-wslite library and I cant get it to work no matter what I do.

Here is the Wslite library again.

[wslite library](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it helpful to use a tool like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) first to figure out what request a service is expecting.  From there it's a matter of using the markup builder to build that request.  The following should work from the groovyConsole:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='0.8.0')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx')
def response = client.send(SOAPAction: 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate') {
    body {
        ConversionRate( xmlns: 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/') {
            FromCurrency('GBP')
            ToCurrency('USD')
        }
    }
}

assert response
assert 200 == response.httpResponse.statusCode

println response.ConversionRateResponse.ConversionRateResult.text()
```

Comment: Ah that's great! Thank you for that conversion and for letting me know about that tool!